# Sensor manager to find the direction of the camera pointer

Tags: android, android-camera

is it possible to use sensor manager to find where am pointing my camera of the mobile ? like towards east/west/north or south.
My requirement is that to show bubbles over camera preview like restaurant, hotel or theater etc.

Thanks

JRH

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float[],%20float[]%29

Comment: AM/Shivam, Can you please eloborate on this ?

Comment: You might need to integrate Augmented Reality stuff

Comment: now, am confused to go with sensor manager alone or some augmented reality stuff as well ?